# Reduce MSVC compiler executable size?

Tags: c, windows

I have a simple hello world program, but the .exe is somehow 100kb big.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  printf("Hello world");

  return 0;
}
```

I'm currently using a .bat file to call the commands.

```
@echo off

call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" x86

cl /nologo /O2 /W3 ./Main.c /FeHello.exe
```

I am using MSVC compiler from Visual Studio 2019 to compile with the command prompt.

Thanks

Comment: Unrelated (??) you might like the [A Whirlwind Tutorial on Creating Really Teensy ELF Executables for Linux](https://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html) article by Brian Raiter.

Comment: 16k for me in vs2022 using the vs integrated  build, not command line

Comment: /O2 is speed, not size. Even with all applicable size switches, the generated basic application gets larger with every new VS version. Go back as far as possible if size is really that important to you. VC6 generates the smallest code if you can live with its limits.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Large size is caused by linking runtime statically. `/MD` switch can be used in order to link it dynamically and shrink size of the executable.

Comment: Mind that if you link runtime libraries dinamically, then you will need to distribute the DLL files along with your application.
These DLL files are not installed by default on Windows systems.
This does not apply to the old VC6 compiler, as its C++ runtime library is included in all Windows systems from XP and above.